# Quadratic Manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there some easy way to transform a quadratic equation like $ax^2+bx+c$ into a quadratic equation of the form $d(x+s)^2+e(x+s)$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are constants and $a,d,e>0$

$-s$ is a root of the function

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would only be of that form if $-s$ is a root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** This is an answer to the problem OP asked before editing.

let $ax^2+bx+c=d(x+s)^2+e(x+s)$, compare coefficients and get the desired form

$ax^2+bx+c=d(x+s)^2+e(x+s)=d(x^2+s^2+2xs)+ex+es$ which gives the equations

$a=d$

$b=2sd+e$

$c=ds^2+es$